# Remote and local repository

Tags: git

I have a `remote git repository` where I have a `remote_branch`.
I cloned the `remote_repository` to my machine and created a `local_branch`.

I now want to `push` the changes from my `local_branch` to the `remote_branch`.
Doing that, I set the `upstream flag`

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/remote_branch local_branch
```

I then `commit` and `stage` my changes and try to `git push` the changed on the `remote_branch`.
I get this message:

```
To git@....git
! [rejected]        remote_branch -> remote_branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@....git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its
remote counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may 
want to specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' 
configuration variable to 'simple', 'current' or 'upstream' to push 
only the current branch.
```

However, when I `push` the changed by

```
 git push origin local_branch:remote_branch
```

It works. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

On your local machine, you seem to be working on a branch named `remote_branch`. This branch is automatically created on your local machine when cloning from the remote repository. When you issue `git push`, the default is to push changes from the current branch. As such, you need to do `git checkout local_branch` first (and provide the commits there).

In general I'd recommend to use the same names as on the remote repository also locally, and have a 1:1 mapping.

Comment: I did the git checkout local_branch -> did not do the trick,,

Comment: Reading it again, could it be that you added your changes (commits) to `local_branch`, while someone else added other commits to the remote repository? If this is the case, you might need to merge or rebase your changes before you can push (and the other push worked because it pushed in fact nothing). `gitk --all` could help visualize the current state.

Comment: nope. i pulled from `remote_branch` on `local_branch`, then changed something in `local_branch` and tried to push `local_branch` to `remote_branch`. Same effect.